# Python Google Drive API - Downloading duplicate files

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, bytesio

So I am trying to download a lot of different files from google drive, then combine them into smaller fewer files. However, for some reason, my code is downloading duplicate files, or potentially just reading the BytesIO object incorrectly. I have pasted the code below and here is just a quick explanation of the file structure.

So I have ~135 folders, containing 52 files each. My goal is to loop through each folder, download the 52 files, then convert those 52 files into one file that is more compressed (get rid of unnecessary/duplicate data).

**Code**

```
def main(temporary_workspace, workspace):
    store = file.Storage('tokenRead.json')
    big_list_of_file_ids = []

    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        q="'MAIN_FOLDER_WITH_SUBFOLDERS_ID' in parents",
        pageSize=1000, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    list_of_folders_and_ids = []
    if not items:
        raise RuntimeError('No files found.')
    else:
        for item in items:
            list_of_folders_and_ids.append((item['name'], item['id']))

    list_of_folders_and_ids.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

    for folder_id in list_of_folders_and_ids:
        start_date = folder_id[0][:-3]
        id = folder_id[1]

        print('Folder: ', start_date, ', ID: ', id)

        query_string = "'{}' in parents".format(id)
        results = service.files().list(
            q=query_string, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
        ).execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        list_of_files_and_ids = []
        if not items:
            raise RuntimeError('No files found.')
        else:
            for item in items:
                list_of_files_and_ids.append((item['name'], item['id']))

        for file_id in list_of_files_and_ids:
            # Downloading the files
            if file_id[1] not in big_list_of_file_ids:
                big_list_of_file_ids.append(file_id[1])
            else:
                print('Duplicate file ID!')
                exit()

            print('\tFile: ', file_id[0], ', ID: ', file_id[1])

            request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id[1])
            fh = io.BytesIO()
            downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
            done = False
            while done is False:
                status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                print("Download: {}".format(int(status.progress() * 100)))

            fh.seek(0)

            temporary_location = os.path.join(tmp_workspace, file_id[0])
            with open(temporary_location, 'wb') as out:
                out.write(fh.read())

            fh.close()

        convert_all_netcdf(temporary_workspace, start_date, workspace, r'Qout_south_america_continental',
                           num_of_rivids=62317)

        os.system('rm -rf %s/*' % tmp_workspace)
```

So as you can see, I first get the ID's of all of the folders, then I loop through each folder and get the 52 files in that folder, then I save all of the 52 files to a temporary folder, convert them into one file, which I save in another directory, and then delete all of the 52 files and move on to the next folder in Google Drive. The problem is, when I compare the files that I compressed with the *convert_all_netcdf* method, they are all the same. I feel as though I am doing something wrong with the **BytesIO** object, do I need to do something more to clear it? It also may be that I am accidentally reading from the same folder every time in the google drive api calls. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but there is a separate bug in your code. You need to iterate your `files.list` until `nextPageToken == null`. I suspect you think that setting the pageSize to 1000, with 53 files in each folder will ensure that you get all 53 in a single fetch. This isn't how pageSize works. `pageSize` is the **maximum** number of results in a fetch, hence the need to keep iterating until nextPageToken is null.

Comment: @pinoyyid so should I just delete that part of the code? It seems the default is 100. Is this just an optimization?

Comment: Please research pageSize because I suspect you are still misunderstanding it. Don't delete any code, just add additional code to loop around files.list until nextPageToken is null.

Comment: @pinoyyid I appreciate that you are trying to help, but I don't see anything like what you are suggesting in the API...

Comment: from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list -  "The maximum number of files to return per page. Partial or empty result pages are possible even before the end of the files list has been reached"

Comment: @pinoyyid Thank you for linking the documentation. What I was saying in my previous comment was that I don't see any methods on that page to accomplish what you are suggesting, which is to loop until the nextPageToken is null.

Comment: indeed not. You need to code the loop yourself. 
You have 53 files in each folder. Imagine you had set pageSize to 10. Clearly you would need to keep calling files.list until nextPageToken==null in order to fetch all 53 files. Your code assumes that by setting pageSize to 1000, that all 53 files will be returned in a single call to files.list. That assumption is incorrect. Your code needs to iterate the call to files.list in exactly the same was as if you had set pageSize to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that this was probably not a great question, and I mainly asked it because I thought I was doing something wrong with the BytesIO object, but I found the answer. I was reading all of the files that I downloaded with a library called Xarray, and I was forgetting to close the connection. This was causing me to only read the first connection on subsequent loops, giving me duplicates. Thanks to anyone who tried!